# flutter transition splash screen to first screen without delay

Tags: flutter

I've just set splash screen on iOS and launch screen looks fine but when move to launch screen to first screen (`MaterialApp` home), image will disappear for a moment. So, you can tell obviously that image was changed.
Is there any workaround to fix this?

Comment: Which screen image is show, first screen or splash screen?

Comment: both are the same image. I want to do like normal native app splash to first screen and load some data and navigate to corresponding page like user not logged in.

Comment: Are you pulling the images form internet or it is in local file system?

Comment: It’s from local.

Comment: Can you show the code and video of the effect, it will be helpful in figuring out the problem.